# Plotting boxplot for multiple numerical columns using seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I'm trying to find outliers for my numerical columns in a dataframe. I need to display boxplots for those columns using subplots. There are like 19 numerical columns. I cant spend time writing down boxplot code for each of the numerical variable using subplot of matplotlib. I need to use some sort of for loop so that python displays boxplot for each column by subplotting them.
I dont want to keep writing this below code

```
plt.subplot()
sns.boxplot(data=df['<column name>']) for every column.
```

It would be very cumbersome.

I need the boxplots displayed in rows and columns. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Is it:

```
sns.catplot(y='value', col='variable', col_wrap=5,
            data=df.melt(), kind='box')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Probably `data=df[desired_columns].melt()` as OP only wants to plot some subset.

Comment: Yes the graph above is exactly how i want to be displayed. So the code which is written sns.catplot is how it needs to be written to get the boxplots that way in rows and columns?

Comment: I used the code and it got me plots but the box plot is hardly visible